# Devise: How to display 'signed_up_but_unconfirmed' on homepage with successful user sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have installed devise, it's working great. But I am not getting how to play with devise messages. I went through the devise wiki but i am not getting it.

When a user successfully signs up, devise just redirects to the homepage, displaying nothing. I checked devise.en.yml and there found this:

```
 signed_up_but_unconfirmed: 'A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account.'
```

Would like to display this on the homepage on signup redirect.

My Registration controller is:

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
    resource = build_resource({})
       resource.build_profile
       respond_with resource        
    end

 end
```

And my sign_up form is:

```
 <div class = "form-signin">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign up</h2>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
   <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Email address"  %>
   <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Password" %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "input-block-level", :placeholder => "Retype the password" %>
   <div><%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary"  %></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

How to do get this message on home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from devise github page:

> Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in
>   was successful or failed. Devise expects your application to call
>   "flash[:notice]" and "flash[:alert]" as appropriate.

The registration controller's create action will set the signed_up_but_unconfirmed message from devise.en in flash[:notice] and redirects.
On the redirected page, in your case the home page, you will have the message in flash[:notice] and have to display that.

```
<%= flash[:notice] unless flash[:notice].blank?%>
```

Adding this to your home page, will display :notice flash messages if any.

I would suggest you to display flash messages in all layouts, so that any flash message set from devise controllers will be displayed to the user irrespective of the redirected page.

Comment: Hey awesome description and advise! Thanks a ton. It worked like charm :-)

Comment: Hey i wanna display only sign up related notice 'signed_up_but_unconfirmed'. Cause devise msges are displaying every sign in. That bit annoying. How to do it related to sign up only??

Comment: One simple way would be to set "" for unwanted messages in devise.yml. flash[:notice].blank? as mentioned in the code above, will return true if it is an empty string-"". So it wont display the flash message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add alert handler in layout file like this,

```
<% if (notice and notice.length > 0) or (alert and alert.length > 0) %>
   <% if notice %>
      <%= notice %>
   <% end %>
   <% if alert %> 
       <%= alert %>
   <% end %>     
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey i wanna display only sign up related notice 'signed_up_but_unconfirmed'. Cause devise msges are displaying every sign in. That bit annoying. How to do it related to sign up only??

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you customize the root_path, below steps will help you resolve the problem:

1. Make sure you have the `= flash[:notice]` in your `application.html.haml`
2. Override the registration controller

   `rails g devise:controllers users -c=registrations`
3. Uncomment the below method in the registratons_controller if you use the `confirmable` module in your model e.g;

   `def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       new_user_session_path
     end`

   **OR**

   only the sing_up_path_for method if you are not using the confirmable module.

   `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     new_user_session_path
   end`