# Devise showing unauthenticated message instead of signed_up_but_unconfirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the default Devise controllers. I assumed when a user created a new account, they'd be redirected to the sign_in page and shown the flash message for `signed_up_but_unconfirmed`. The redirect is happening, but the flash message being displayed is `unauthenticated`.

Why would I need to tell Devise to show the `signed_up_but_unconfirmed` message when new accounts are created? That seems like the way it should work out of the box.

And more importantly, how do I configure it to show `signed_up_but_unconfirmed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538292/3921815) in an older question. The short of it is this:

Override the registration controller:

```
rails g devise:controllers users -c=registrations
```

Uncomment the `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` method in the `registratons_controller`:

```ruby
def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_user_session_path
end
```